# Prevent Oracle from cutting leading zeros of my floats like 0.1 0.2 0.5 etc

Tags: sql, oracle, floating-point

I've got an oracle query like this:

```
SELECT floatColum0,floatColum1,ROUND(floatColum2,2) from table;
```

which is returning values like that:

```
.2 , 1.23, .23
```

how can I get something like that? (leading zeros)

```
0.2, 1.23, 0.23 ?
```

Comment: But it isn't normal for that to happen. It should have the leading zero!

Comment: @aF: It has nothing to do with what is normal and what is not. The above question represents a use case that is utterly pointless. In all fairness, it is not normal to bother about the string representation of a query output. zerkms: +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't the numbers whose leading zeroes are being `cut`, but rather the **string representation** of the number. Mostly this is not a concern as application logic is used with data from a database, which works with the actual data (in this case the number itself) and not its string representation. But if you absolutely require this, you can format the string within the query:

```
SET numformat 99.99;
SELECT floatColum0,floatColum1,ROUND(floatColum2,1) from table;
```

This should do the trick, but again remember, it is a pretty pointless exercise. For additional details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211

Comment: +1 : String representations of floats are presentation issues.  And presentation shoul be kept separate from data storage and manipulatation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be Regional Settings.

Make this:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Regional and Language Settings
3. Customize
4. Display Leading Zeros

and change the value for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting it as varchar and using a case statement to add a zero if the first character is a '.' (and adding nothing if its anything else).

Im not an Oracle expert but I dont think you could 'add' zeros without changing data type.